# Xamarin Forms Create scrollable timeline

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I need to create the following image in Xamarin Forms:
[image]

The first thing I did was set the schedule as background image, but then its not easy to use. The next thing I thougt of, was a Grid, but a Grid doesn't work because you need to set the height of a row and you can have random rows. I am running out of ideas! :(

I know this website is for coding problems, but I would really appreciate it, because I am stuck on this issue for 2 weeks now and I want to move further with this feature!

Let me know! :)

Comment: there are third party calendar controls that do this - this is a non-trivial UI

Comment: [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/calendar/overview) as a realy awesome Agenda like control for this, there's also a [Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/calendar/view-modes/calendar-agendaview) one, search for Schedule Controls in Xamarin.Forms and you will find alot of options for this

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will take a look into those :)

Comment: Not too sure about your "random row". But as the image above, you can still use GridView, let's say height of each row (1 hour) is 200. Then the height of the first event could be 100 and VerticalOption=end. Second height 150. Third height 300 with RowSpan=2, etc.

Comment: Or just set half an hour as one row and play with RowSpan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to create a scrollable timeline, I will suggest that install **[Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfSchedule](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/scheduler/getting-started)** nuget to achieve that.

Here is the day scrollable time line sample code of Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms"
             xmlns:schedule="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms"
             x:Class="XamarinTableView.Views.SyncCalendaPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="Start" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <schedule:SfSchedule x:Name="schedule"
                                    BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                                    ScheduleView="DayView" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the `.cs` sample code:

```
schedule.ScheduleView = ScheduleView.DayView;
ScheduleAppointmentCollection scheduleAppointmentCollection = new ScheduleAppointmentCollection();
scheduleAppointmentCollection.Add(new ScheduleAppointment()
{
    StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 24, 09, 0, 0),
    EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 24, 09, 30, 0),
    Subject = "Client Meeting",
    Notes="1111",
    MinHeight = 30,
    Color = Color.FromHex("#FFD80073")
});
scheduleAppointmentCollection.Add(new ScheduleAppointment()
{
    StartTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 24, 11, 0, 0),
    EndTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 24, 12, 30, 0),
    Subject = "Anniversary",
    Notes = "1111",
    Color = Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139")
});
schedule.DataSource = scheduleAppointmentCollection;

DayViewSettings dayViewSettings = new DayViewSettings();
dayViewSettings.VerticalLineColor = Color.LightGray;
dayViewSettings.VerticalLineStrokeWidth = 5;
schedule.DayViewSettings = dayViewSettings;
```

The effect:

[image]

Also can refer to [Appointments in Xamarin Scheduler (SfSchedule)](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/scheduler/data-bindings) to custom more appearance of it.